# How to create a Java program with files from different locations

Tags: java

In

```
C:\Dev\Java\MyFirstJavaClass\
```

I have a file named `MyFirstJavaClass.java`, so the path looks like this

```
C:\Dev\Java\MyFirstJavaClass\MyFirstJavaClass.java
```

and in `"C:\Dev\Java\MyFirstJavaClass"` I have a subdirectory called `'src'`.
So the path looks like this:

```
C:\Dev\Java\MyFirstJavaClass\src
```

In this directory I want to put a file named `"MyName.java"`, so the path would look like this

```
C:\Dev\Java\MyFirstJavaClass\src\MyName.java
```

In `MyFirstJavaClass.java` I have this code

```
public class MyFirstJavaClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("You have your first Java program running!!\n\n");
    }
}
```

This file compiles, but I'd like to add the files in `./src` into my `MyFirstJavaClass.java` file, how do I `#include` the file(s) in 'src' in `MyFirstJavaClass.java`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a classpath is (first thing) and what a process environment is (second thing)?

Comment: And, do you understand java's package structure and how this relates to the file system? Either way you `import` things in java, not `#include`.

Comment: you need to create the file in a java packages and import it.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should check some tutorials about packages and classpath .
https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm

2) You should create the package and structure as described below

`package dev.java.myfirstjavaclass;
public class MyFirstJavaClass { 
}`

It will create your class file inside the folder structure `dev/java/myfirstjavaclass` in your `classpath`, Also as per the java naming conventions packages name should be in lower cases.

`package dev.java.myfirstjavaclass.src;
public class MyName{
}`

It will create your class file inside the folder structure `dev/java/myfirstjavaclass/src` inside your `classpath`.

Now as you have called `#include` the file. You have to use the `import` statement to include the file where you want to use it.

```
import dev.java.myfirstjavaclass.src.MyName;

public class MyFirstJavaClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      MyName test=new MyName();
   }
 }
```

3) Also look some tutorials on objects and java concepts about how to use them.